# Atomic update of conda environments?

Tags: anaconda, conda

Has anyone attempted to atomically update a conda environment. I have a shared conda environment that constantly has something running on it but I want to be able to update it without putting the environment in an unstable stage during the update.

A possible solution could be creating a clone each time but I'm trying to avoid that.